# Return type of child class function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I expected that `validate()` function of child class returns the type of `checks()` child class function. But as you see it returns the type of parent class function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0AOAnA9sIhABQCUamW0w+AdstGEkrjALzRIAWAlhADoAbmBC8AJs3jkA3NAD086CQC28HvnEUEyYaIlTyALmhD8E9FSy51AV1x0mLNjKoBfS1hFjJSaRQxqGnpGZlYOLj5BYG54YABrUjJXK2gbJHtHMJd3TxwCP2A-cRpYhKS0Dw90UEgYAGVbACMdFHgADz86cRhWyiw8QmJyfupaBhRsiJ5+PR9DZIUlVXVuTW1EJDmDP2NTc3E86zsHJ3DXLGqBgrji0rjEkcDqdMzoAHJYkBB8d4voKqWcaMXgTMB0IjQTh0eAAd2gjRam1kNRCKBsEGwIXgUOgoOQ4KIAkGRCgKNRDHwIHgAh+AHMSBisQx4Ml0EA)

Could you explain why and how to fix it?

```js
class Test {
  process() {
    const attrs = this.validate(); // (method) Test.validate(): void

    return attrs;
  }

  validate() {
    const attrs = this.checks();

    return attrs;
  }

  protected checks() {}
}

class SubTest extends Test {
  process() {
    const attrs = this.validate(); // (method) Test.validate(): void

    return attrs;
  }

  protected checks() {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
  process() {
    const attrs = this.validate(); // (method) Test.validate(): void

    return attrs;
  }

  validate<T>(): T {
    const attrs = this.checks();

    return attrs;
  }

  protected checks(): any {}
}

class SubTest extends Test {
  process() {
    const attrs = this.validate<ReturnType<SubTest['checks']>>(); // (method) Test.validate(): Number

    return attrs;
  }

  protected checks(): Number {
    return 1;
  }
}


class Sub2Test extends Test {
  process() {
    const attrs = this.validate<ReturnType<Sub2Test['checks']>>(); // (method) Test.validate(): String

    return attrs;
  }

  protected checks(): String {
    return 'ssssss';
  }
}

const instance = new SubTest();
const response = instance.process();

console.log(response);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. But unfortunately it doesn't implement flexibility that i needed.

Comment: Could you share more details about what you wanna do @Doniv. Maybe we can have difference approaches